# Is $f_n (x)$ pointwise convergent??

Tags: real-analysis, definition, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

$\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions, where $f_n : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined as:
$$\begin{equation*}
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
          0,                            \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad x<n-\frac{1}{n} \ \ or \ \ x>n+\frac{1}{n} \\
          n(x-(n-\frac{1}{n})),         \quad \quad \ \ \  n-\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq n \\
          n(n+\frac{1}{n}-x), \quad \quad \ \ \ \ \ n\leq x\leq n+\frac{1}{n}
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$$
I'm not able to mathematically describe the function to which the above sequence converges.
Since,

$$\begin{equation*}
f_1(x)=\begin{cases}
          0,                             \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad x<0 \ or \ x>2\\
          x,      \quad \quad \quad   \quad \quad  0\leq x\leq 1 \\
          2-x, \quad \quad \ \ \ \ \ 1\leq x\leq 2
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}\implies f_(1) =1$$
$$\begin{equation*}
f_2(x)=\begin{cases}
          0,                     \ \ \ \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad x<1.5 \ \ or \ \ x>2.5\\
          2x-3,     \  \quad   \quad \quad  1.5\leq x\leq 2 \\
          5-2x, \ \quad \quad \ \ \ \ \ 2\leq x\leq 2.5
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*} \implies f_2(2) =1$$
$$\begin{equation*}
f_5(x)=\begin{cases}
          0,                     \ \ \ \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad x<4.8 \ \ or \ \ x>5.2\\
          5x-24,      \quad   \quad \quad  4.8\leq x\leq 5 \\
          26-5x, \ \quad \quad \ \ \ \ \ 5\leq x\leq 5.2
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}\implies f_5(5) =1$$It seems that it eventually converges to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ except at $\infty$ where $f_n(n)\rightarrow1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

**Can I write that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined as:
$$\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
          0,                            \quad \quad \quad x<\infty \ \ or \ \ x>-\infty \\
          1,         \quad \quad \ \ \ \  x=n, \ n\rightarrow\infty
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}\ \ \ ?$$
Is this the correct way of expressing a function
Or is it that $\{f_n\}$ isn't convergent at all?**

Comment: The point (ha!) is that the point where $f_n(x) \neq 0$ moves. So in the limit, if you're interested in the **pointwise** behaviour at a **fixed** $x$, for $n$ sufficiently large it'll definitely be $0$. So $f(x) = 0$ is the pointwise limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **pointwise** limit means we are interested in what happens to $f_n(x)$ for **fixed** $x$ as $n \to \infty$.
In this case, notice how if we fix $x$, then for any $n > x + 1$ (for example), we must have $f_n(x) = 0$ since
$$ x < n - 1 < n - \frac{1}{n}. $$
Hence as $n \to \infty$, $f_n(x) \to 0$ (and indeed equals $0$ for $n$ large).
Therefore the pointwise limit is precisely $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

What you are finding with your observation that $f_n(n) = 1$ for all $n$ is that whilst the **pointwise** limit is $0$, this convergence is **not** uniform. This is definitely a very important observation about the sequence $f_n$, but it does not affect the pointwise behaviour.

Comment: but there isn't any point of non-uniform convergence. Right?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. If by "point" you mean a literal point where non-uniform convergence happens, then no, there isn't any one point, since the "violation" is moving (and would have to, since we *do* have pointwise convergence to $0$). If instead you mean "is there any point in caring about this non-uniform convergence", then sure, it's interesting in its own right---depending on what you're doing pointwise but not uniform convergence might be plenty.

Comment: I meant the former. Thanks!